# calculate radius of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be sequence such that

$$a_1 = a_0 = 1$$

$$a_{n+1}=a_n+ a_{n-1}$$

show that the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty \:}a_nx^n$ is $\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Thanks!

Comment: $a_n +1 =a_n +a_n -1$, you didn't mean that. Did you?

Comment: If you know about the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), then read [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

Comment: If you do the ratio test on your series, you'll see the radius of convergence is $1/L$ where $L$ is the limit of $a_{n+1}/a_n$ (supposing it exists). From the recurrence it's easy to show that if it exists, it is $(1+\sqrt{5})/2.$ So you just need to reason why the limit of that ratio exists. There are many ways to do that, give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ratio test, the radius of convergence is

$$|x| < \big[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\big]^{-1} =L^{-1}$$

If the limit exists, then from the recursion

$$L - 1= \lim\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1=\lim\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}= L^{-1}$$

Then $L^{-1} = \frac{-1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}.$

To prove the limit exists, first establish the following identity for $m>n$:

$$a_ma_{n+1}-a_{m+1}a_{n}= (-1)^na_{m-n}.$$

Rearranging we get

$$\Big|\frac{a_{m+1}}{a_{m}}-\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\Big| = \frac{a_{m-n}}{a_ma_n},$$

This can be used to establish that $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence since the RHS converges to $0$ as $m,n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You can find explicitly what a_n are: consider the next matrix A=[1,1;1,0] and notice (a_n+1, a_n)=A*(a_n,a_n-1)
From here you can by induction show: (a_n+1, a_n)=A^n *(a_1, a_0)
Now in order to calculate A^n use A=(I+B) where B=[0,1;0,0] and newton's binomial.
From here you can use caushy-hadamrd easily and finish.

Answer (score 1):

The terms are Fibonacci numbers, and the [ratio of consecutive ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Limit_of_consecutive_quotients) is $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  Now you can use the ratio test.